# Is it possible to execute Jenkins jobs from Powershell or Bash or Groovy scripts?

Tags: bash, powershell, jenkins, groovy

I have separated quite small Jenkins jobs.

Now I need to configure another job which depending on the selected by the user parameters (selected probably through checkboxes?) will execute some of them.

I would like to start them from Powershell or Bash or Groovy script. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Groovy in a Postbuild/pipeline step, you can start the job via the Jenkins API.

For example, something like this for parameterless builds:

```
import hudson.model.*
Jenkins.instance.getItem("My Job").scheduleBuild(5)
```

And something like this for parameterized builds:

```
import hudson.model.*
Jenkins.instance.getItem("My Job").scheduleBuild( 5, new Cause.UpstreamCause( currentBuild ), new ParametersAction([ new StringParameterValue( "My Parameter Name", "My Parameter Value" ) ]));
```

You can also use the [Jenkins Rest API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) for the rest.  For example, by hitting the following url:

Parameterless:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build
```

Parameterized:

```
curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters?MyParameterName=MyParameterValue
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to set Jenkins jobs parameters as well (Jenkins.instance.getItem("My Job").parameters ?). I would like to use parameters from current job.

Comment: Yep!  I have updated the answer with more examples. :)

Comment: Could you please add "import hudson.model.*" to your example to avoid "unable to resolve class" exceptions, please?

Comment: // to avoid groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Jenkins for class: Script1
// error you need to add following line:
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Unfortunately, script is still failing with following error: No such property: currentBuild

Comment: In regards to the currentBuild question, it will be undefined if you are not in a pipeline step.  If you are in postbuild groovy step, you can get the same variable via "manager.build".  If you are in a groovy system step, you can use just the "build" variable.

Comment: Thanks! I used "manager.build". Is it possible to wait for job execution end before exiting from Groovy script?

Comment: In regards to the waiting for the execution to end, that is a little tricky..  If you are in a postbuild groovy step, then I think your only option would be to poll the job until it finishes (i.e. search for the job matching your parameters and then check the status for SUCCESS/FAILUE.  This will probably involve a loop and a sleep function).  That being said, is it a must for the job to end in the groovy postbuild step?  If not, there are better alternatives for this kind of management.  How about the "Trigger/call builds on other projects" build step?

Comment: That build step has a checkbox that waits for the job to complete before moving onto the next step.  Pipelines are also a great alternative.  They are written in groovy and have "waitUntil" blocks that can stop a build until some condition is met.

Comment: My idea to wait is as follows: import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def JobToRun = "MyJob"
def lastbuild = Jenkins.instance.getItem(JobToRun).getLastBuild()
def lastbuildResult = lastbuild.result.toString()
def lastbuildNumber = lastbuild.number.toString()


while (lastbuildResult.equals("null")) {lastbuildResult = lastbuild.result.toString()}
println("Status of the last (" + lastbuildNumber + ") build of the: " + JobToRun + " was: " + lastbuildResult)

Comment: That could work...  If you are going down this path, there is also a schedulebuild2 function that seems like it returns a Future object that you use to wait until the job is done (based on the [javadoc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractProject.html#scheduleBuild2(int))).  I've never used this function, so I won't be of much help with it though.

Answer (score 0):

sample:

```
import hudson.model.*
def actions=[]
  def plist=[ ];
  ["ok":"ok","label":"master"].each {k,v->    
    plist << new hudson.model.StringParameterValue(k,"$v","");
  }
actions.add(new hudson.model.ParametersAction(plist));
def future = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("samples/testPipeline").scheduleBuild2(0,actions as hudson.model.Action[] );
future.get().getLog()
```